# Detect at runtime if OPENMP is being used in a C++ program

Tags: c++, openmp

I'd like to know at runtime if a C++ program has been compiled with OPENMP enabled or not. There are some things that OPENMP 2.0 cannot easily do so I'd like to fake them with another mechanism. However if the code is compiled with OPENMP disabled then I'd like to also disable my other mechanism and run everything serially.

For example

```
if( isOpenMPEnabled() )
    runFakeParallelAlgorithm();
else
    runSequentialAlgorithm();
```

How could I implement

```
bool isOpenMPEnabled()
```

I should say we are using OPENMP 2.0

Comment: [this site](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH4D_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlf161.aix.doc/proguide/openmpc.html) claims that the symbol `_OPENMP` is defined if openmp was enabled on compilation, though elsewhere I read that the macro only tells you if the compiler supports OpenMP...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the /openmp flag was passed to the compiler and compilation was successful, a preprocessor directive will be added that you can use to check this at runtime:

```
#if defined(_OPENMP)
   #pragma omp ...
#endif
```

Comment: And this is across all compilers which support OPENMP 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes, the _OPENMP define is not only set if OpenMP is supported, but it also contains the version encoded as the year and month of the OpenMP version supported by the compiler.

Comment: "supported by the compiler" vs "enabled with /openmp". Which is it? The compiler may support openmp but if /openmp is not passed then it is disabled. Can you clarify?

Comment: Unless you manually `#define _OPENMP` somewhere in your code (or use a command line option to define it) the macro `_OPENMP` will not be defined unless openmp was enabled on compilation.    If someone manually defines such a macro when not using openmp, they can only blame themselves if the test above doesn't work.